# How would I center this for the android

Tags: android, xml, textview

I am trying to center two Text Views horizontally so that are next to each other at the top of the screen.  I am doing this because one of the TextViews will be larger than the other.  Here is my code

```
<TableRow 
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="open" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Ctrl O" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get your question bit is this what you are looking for:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="open" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:text="Ctrl O" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I meant center the two texts horizontally on the first row of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

So you want your views next to each other and in the center of the screen like this?

```
|    View1|reallylongView2    |
```

Generally try to avoid table rows unless you actually want to have a table. If you want what I've shown above, the best thing to do would be to have a single text view, particularly since the order of the text might need to change if you ever internationalize your app.

Otherwise try a relative layout parent, with a centered horizontal linear layout child, which in turn contains both of your text views like so:

```
<RelativeLayout
     ...
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
         <TextView ... />
         <TextView ... />
     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Otherwise you need to clarify what you're looking for. A screenshot, or ascii art would be helpful.